# Terminate button has vanished, Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

The terminate button which is usually below the code has gone (Eclipse), also when I click run all the terminate, resume etc are greyed out, how do I get them back ?

Comment: `"The terminate button which is usually below the code has gone, also when I click run all the terminate, resume etc are greyed out, how do I get them back ?"` -- Sorry, but what are you talking about? Are you talking about an IDE that you're using? If so, what IDE?

Comment: lol, the terminate button has just vanished - the red stop sign, i'm in the Java perspective, its there when i'm in the debugging perspective but not the java.

Comment: Should this question should be moved to Super User?

Comment: NOT! Plz, refer: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6029/can-questions-about-ides-be-asked-here-if-not-then-wheredont-suggest-stackov

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of others it was the console window that had gone, got it back by clicking window - show view - console.